# Bootstrap modal form, Div not containing form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help figuring out why the div tag is not containing the form like it should.

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <form class="register" name="register">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" id="firstName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" id="lastName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" id="emailAddress">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Birth Day mm/dd/yyyy" class="form-control" id="birthday">
                    </div>
                </form>                                         
            </div>
```

This is the code for the particular div in question.If you have any thoughts on this it would be very helpful.

You can see the [source code for the index page on this link](http://pastebin.com/bsd1GWwB), and a [working demo on this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3jv8z84/). To see the problematic behavior, resize the result box to a medium display.

All the js and css is default bootstrap except where I have created my own css.

Comment: what's the exact problem you're facing

Comment: is this within another form? can you show more html? it is helpful to see where the modal is

Comment: much better if you could provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: The the form within <div class="modal-body"> doesn't wrap the form inputs. When run in a browser the inputs are not within the modal body as expected. they just float outside the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why this happens:**

This issue happens because the `col-XX-XX` class floats the elements. The floating causes the `div`s with the fields to *overflow* their containing `div` (`.modal-body`).

**How to fix it:**

As you are adding columns (`.col-md-6`), you should place them within a row (`.row`). Add the class `.row` to the form, and let Bootstrap work its magic:

```
<form class="register row" name="register">
```

You can see it working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3jv8z84/2/, and it doesn't need additional CSS rules :)

---

EDIT (Previous answer): 
Make the `.modal-body` grow dynamically and adjust it's height to the floating elements. You can do that by adding this simple CSS:

```
.modal-body {
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

And that will solve the problem, as you can see on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3jv8z84/1/